# Can't Parse RSS XML with PHP

Tags: php, rss, xml-parsing

I have some RSS that I am trying to parse from this URL:
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12797541

But when I try to parse it using PHP doing this:

```
$yahoo_response = new SimpleXMLElement($yahoo_url , 0, true);

echo $yahoo_response->rss->channel->item->title;
echo $yahoo_response->rss->channel->item->description;
```

Nothing gets outputed.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?  I just need the current forecast bit.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: echo (string) $yahoo_response->rss->channel->item->title;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root element is `<rss>`, which is represented by the `SimpleXmlElement` you loaded into `$yahoo_response`.

```
echo $yahoo_response->getName();  // rss
```

You are trying to do `<rss><rss>` when you should do:

```
echo $yahoo_response->channel->item->title;
echo $yahoo_response->channel->item->description;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that RSS feeds are best parsed using a library.

I've had much success with [magpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/).

But your immediate problem is that you are passing a URL to simplexml, instead of the xml itself.

try `$xml = file_get_contents($yahoo_url);` first.