# Question regarding simplexml_load_file, root element and document element

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am sure I am being an idiot here, but something is not working correctly.

I've got this very basic code.

```
$Xml = simplexml_load_file($Url);
```

If I do a debug print of $xml it comes out like I expect it to. The XML looks like this, very simple

```
<Root>
   <Error>
        <ErrorNo>0</ErrorNo>
   </Error>
</Root>
```

All I want to do is get the error number. So I have tried this, and it doesn't return anything!

```
echo $Xml->Root->Error->ErrorNo;
```

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: `$root = simplexml_load_file($Url);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't Parse RSS XML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101231/cant-parse-rss-xml-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take out `Root` ... as `Root` becomes the `$Xml` element

```
echo $Xml->Error->ErrorNo;
```

Comment: To add to what @Mihai has said, sometimes it's useful to print_r the response. `echo "<PRE>";print_r($Xml);echo "</PRE>";` to see what the created object looks like.